# Empty set as retract of the terminal object in TOP

Tags: category-theory

I believe that $\emptyset$ cannot be a retract of the terminal object $1$ in TOP, because there are no arrows from $1$ to $\emptyset$ in TOP and consequently there cannot be a retraction $r:1\to\emptyset$ and a section $s:\emptyset\to 1$ with

$\operatorname{id}_\emptyset = r\circ s$

Am I correct?

**Background**:

In Borceux's Handbook of Categorical Algebra 2 on page 351 at one point he concludes that $1\otimes 1$ is a retract of $1$ and therefore $1\otimes 1$ is either empty or a singleton. He then goes on to rule out the first case by invoking the adjoint of the tensor product and various bijections.

After briefly thinking about it I would replace this last part by the proof I have suggested above. If I missed something and the additional complexity is necessary, kindly point out how.

Comment: I think your argument is correct. Borceux's proof seems to be a roundabout way of saying the same thing.